# Is it acceptable to ask how to improve my own music and DJing?

Tags: support

I make and perform house and techno. Is it acceptable to ask how to improve my own music and DJing from the perspective of a listener or a music fan?

I know there is sound production SE site for improving actual sounds as a producer and sound engineer. Now if I want the feedback from listeners, may I ask here or at some other SE site?

Comment: If you want to be listened and evaluated by other DJs, I suggest  [Soonvibes](http://www.soonvibes.com/en/welcome). Other DJs like you will vote, comment your tracks, give you advices...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can ask these questions here.

Remember what is not allowed (from the [tour](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour)) :

> - Anything not directly related to music history or appreciation
> - Questions that are primarily **opinion-based**

If you want to ask us if we like your work, and how to improve yourself it would **opinion based**.

Answer (score 4):

It's just not a good fit here at Stack Exchange, because the concept of the site is to provide fact-based answers to questions.  Questions that seek opinions and suggestions are generally discouraged, although there have been a few questions asked about bands/artists with similar musical style.

Answer (score 2):

It is acceptable to ask on-topic questions whose answers will help you with your DJing. There are some questions that might be relevant already:

[Standard vinyl vs Audiophile/Weighted vinyl - What's the difference?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/638/standard-vinyl-vs-audiophile-weighted-vinyl-whats-the-difference)

[Should I store my vinyl records side by side or in piles?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/249/should-i-store-my-vinyl-records-side-by-side-or-in-piles)

[How can I know if I'm damaging my hearing when listening to headphones?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/17/how-can-i-know-if-im-damaging-my-hearing-when-listening-to-headphones)

When it comes to technique, [music.stackexchange.com](https://music.stackexchange.com/) might be a more appropriate place for some kinds of questions:

https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/40588/intro-outro-standard-practices-for-song-to-be-included-in-dj-set

https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14291/what-is-harmonic-mixing-mix-in-key

The important thing is to ask questions in a way that they can be answered meaningfully and with a degree of objectivity. "how can I improve my own music and DJing?", for example, is too broad a question to give a good answer to. "Which of these songs is better?" is **primarily** opinion-based and would also not be suitable. For that reason, this site may not be the best if you are looking for general feedback.