# Are we allowed to ask people for advice on music clips with included links?

Tags: support, scope

I am a bit of a newbie to making music, and I'm wondering if I'm allowed to ask questions about my tracks. I'm not advertising youtube channels or anything like that(it is a beepbox link), but I'm a little confused on what this site is all about.

For Example:

I am working on a recreation of *Track Name* by *Author*, using *Instrument/Sounds* and I am having trouble figuring out what chord I should be using to re-create section *timestamp* through *timestamp*. Anyone have any ideas?

Link: [Empty Beepbox](https://beepbox.co)

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Is it acceptable to ask how to improve my own music and DJing?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/316). Considering SE is not a personal help site, one might consider: will my question be *also* useful for future readers? You probably could generalize the question to not about you specifically, but if it's only useful to you (and only you), then perhaps it's not suitable for SE.

Comment: This one is different. I am asking how if I can include a link, and I'm going ot be asking things about "this chord harmony transition better witchmacolit"

Comment: Could you please add the (hypothetical) question using a fake link (or `example.com`) as part of this meta question to make it clearer? As far as I'm aware, musical taste is personal, so one chord harmony transition might feel good to someone, but not to others, and that might become primarily opinion-based... because any chord harmony transition can be better or worse to anyone (or in other word, "polling answer", which SE really discourages)

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: On that case, I think this question is now a dupe of [Are identifying chords or notes in a song on topic?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/66)

Comment: This is asking if I am allowed to include links...

Comment: Links are irrelevant in this case. You can provide [any links](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/328) for others' convenient, but the more important point is the topic. If the topic is already off-topic, then the discussion about providing links is moot :/

Comment: So they are allowed?

Comment: I'm afraid you're mixing 2 things: providing links is okay for additional context/supporting data, but the topic you're asking about identifying chord is off-topic. So you can't ask that question on here.

Comment: Which SO site would I go to ask my hypothetical question in this case?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no existing Stack Exchange site for this kind of question. Perhaps try other sites, like [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/musictheory/comments/arzejv/chord_progression_questions_february_18_2019/).

Comment: Ok then. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several aspects in your question that I will try to answer to.

### Asking people for advice...

Asking people for advice is in general closed as **too broad** and **opinion based**. These questions tend to accumulate endless answers and it's hard to detect a correct answer.

### ... on personal work

In addition to be **too broad** and **opinion based**, the fact that it concerns a user's personal work will likely be useful for OP, but useless for the rest of the community and for the internet in general.

### Posting links

Posting links is allowed when it's relevant to understand a question, but if the question is already off-topic, it will not turn it into on-topic. Then we encourage people to use hosting services that are famous (Youtube, Soundcloud...) and that don't require to create an account and login.